# How to override css-setting for the elements of nested table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

CSS:

```
table.t_group  tbody th
{
    text-align: left;
}

table.t_group_matches tbody th
{
text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="t_group">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:200px">123</td>
            <td style="width:200px">456</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot><tr><td colspan="2">
        <table class="t_group_matches">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th>Some text to be centered</th>
            </tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </td></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

The pointed text is not centered...

Please advise, how to make it centered?

P.S. I could add style specification into tag itself (that works), but I don't like to move that 'stuff' out from css file.

P.P.S.

If that is essential, my 'doctype':

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

P.P.P.S.

If you know any new features (html5, css3) that could work please also advise.

Comment: Does your nested table have a width? If not, it's likely working just fine, but your nested table is only as wide as your text inside, so it only looks as if it's aligned left in relation to the parent. Set the nested table's width to 100% and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Why you didn't put that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is centered, just the table doesn't fill the width of its enclosing area:

```
table.t_group_matches {width:100%}
```

Comment: Downvoter-without-explanation, you're a fool. The mispelling doesn't solve the problem, of course if you put in the effort to check that, you'd know.

Comment: Of course, yours wouldn't work without the correction in spelling either, did I really need to explain that to merit down-voting?

Comment: @jerluc, the OP asked a question. You can point out a minor side issue that doesn't address the problem, or focus on the main point. If you think that pointing out the main issue and not the side one merits a down vote, by that logic, your answer, which doesn't even address the main problem, should merit more than a down vote...

Comment: Point accepted, although this is not an issue of the "main" issue or a "side" issue. Simply put, your solution will __never__ fix the issue. Similarly mine will __never__ fix the issue. The collaboration of the two solutions is the only way for the issue to be resolved.

Comment: @jerluc, I call that a petty way of looking at things, but feel free to see things whatever way you want.

Comment: Petty? Maybe you're misunderstanding the point of an open knowledge-base if you believe collaborative problem-solving is "petty". I'm sorry your down-vote meant so much to you, and I'd be happy to remove the vote provided you'd revise your answer to reflect the fact that my answer clearly has just as much importance as yours (additionally I apparently can't remove my vote without you editting your answer).

Comment: @jerluc, I'm not editing my post. I don't care about the downvote. I noticed the mispelling, which is why my initial post corrected that issue (note that my css matches the markup correctly). I care that people downvote for reasons like that. The knowledge base is supposed to contain info that is upvoted if it is valued and useful, and downvoted if it is "wrong" or misleading etc. I think that downvoting because "your answer isn't a perfect solution" is a misunderstanding of the meaning of votes, especially if it is a valuable answer to the question. So yes, I think that's petty.

Comment: Guys, come on! The idea of problem is correct: internal table should be 100% width. Actually, I also have a misprint in my example. I have a test.html file where fir 100% width didn't work because of that misprint also... (will correct the question now).

Comment: Stop bickering you two...besides, I had already answered the question as a comment. ;)